# R: look for words that do not contain a sequence of characters from a set

Tags: regex, r, search

I'm trying to find from a vector any words that do not contain consecutive vowels, which I defined as `[aeiou]`. For example, I'd want 'Alaska' or 'Mississippi', but not 'Georgia' or 'Hawaii'. I know `{2,}` specifies two or more of something, and `[^...]` not something. But I couldn't figure out how to combine them under grep. Help?

`states <- c('Alaska','Georgia','Hawaii','Mississippi')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You pretty much already have the answer for this:

```
states[!grepl("[aeiou]{2}", states)]
[1] "Alaska"      "Mississippi"
```

I would just use the logical negation in your extraction from `states` (as above) instead of trying to write a more complex regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
\b(?![a-z]*[aeiou]{2})[a-z]+\b
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/45

For `r` it would be `\\b(?![a-z]*[aeiou]{2})[a-z]+\\b`

Run this with `perl=True`

Comment: I just tried running it in R `grepl("\\b(?![a-z]*[aeiou]{2})[a-z]+\\b", states, perl = TRUE)` and the result is `FALSE` for all elements of the `states` vector provided by the OP. Without `perl = TRUE`, it is not a valid R regular expression.

Comment: Not `perl =True`. `'True'!=TRUE` Also think the trailing pattern '[a-z]+' is not likely to be helpful and possibly harmful.

Comment: And even with `perl=TRUE` , it still fails.